# Comprehension including index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, list-comprehension

I have the following code in Python. What would be the equivalent in Javascript? In fact, I would like to know how to access the index of the array.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
evenLetters = [letter for (index, letter) in enumerate(letters) if index % 2 == 0]
```

print(evenLetters)

Output:

```
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const evenLetters = letters.filter((_, i) => !(i % 2))
```